# Perl - replace line in txt file with different matches

Tags: perl, replace, line

I've just started learning Perl this morning and my main aim was to replace lines of text. Suppose I have the following text file;

```
manufacturer=BMW
manufacturer=Honda
manufacturer=Mercedes
manufacturer=Toyota
manufacturer=Noble
manufacturer=Maserati
manufacturer=Jaguar
manufacturer=Ford
```

I want to replace all the lines so that the text file looks like this;

```
manufacturer=XXX
manufacturer=XXX
manufacturer=XXX
manufacturer=XXX
manufacturer=XXX
manufacturer=XXX
manufacturer=XXX
manufacturer=XXX
```

I've learnt how to replace a line of text which matches a particular case with my intended text as follows ;

```
s/BMW/XXX/ig
```

but considering in this file I have different cases, I don't want to keep updating the perl code with different manufacturers (Honda, mercedes, Toyota) everytime and then re-running the code. Surely, there must be a way in which I can simply search for lines beginning with (without worrying about the manufacturer)

```
manufacturer=*whatever*
```

and then replace the entire line with

```
manufacturer=XXX
```

can somebody please shed some light on how to go about doing this?

Comment: If you want to change *all* the lines, you can simply print `manufacturer=XXX` once per line in the file. I.e. `perl -lne'print "manufacturer=XXX"' input > output`

Comment: Thanks TLP. Will this overwrite each line in the existing file with 'manufacturer=XXX'?

Comment: It will *write* a line for each line in the file to a new file. I do not recommend overwriting for newbies, but you can do so with the `-i` flag. Do remember that changes are irreversible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A job for regular expressions:

```
s/manufacturer=.*/manufacturer=XXX/g
```

Per your comment, this matches everything between `=` and EOL and replaces it with `XXX`.

Comprehensive docs [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: @TLP Yeah, as I mentioned op may need to tweak the RegEx as needed.  A perfect RegEx to match all makes/models of cars on the planet wouldn't be a trival task (unless, as in op's sample data set, the make is always between `=` and EOL of course)

Comment: Thanks again. Yes the make is always between '=' and EOL.

Comment: You didn't mention it, as it happens, which is why I did. I believe I would just use `s/^(?<=manufacturer=).*$/XXX/` to remove any character, as the format seems to imply that there wont be other data after the car name.

Comment: This will also replace `designer=Matt Smith` with `designer=XXX`, which isn't what was asked for.

Comment: @Barodin Yeah yeah, I know.  I made an assumption that op's data set reflected what is in the question, in the same way you made an assumption that there's a requirement to have `manufacturer` at the start of each line.  But I won't downvote you for it.  ;)  Anyway, answer updated.

Answer (score 4):

The way I would write this is

```
s/^manufacturer=\K.+/XXX/
```

The `^` at the beginning makes sure the `manufacturer=` starts at the beginning of the string, instead of just appearing in it anywhere.

The `\K` (for *Keep*) metacharacter means to ignore all of the preceding stuff in the substitution, so the pattern *matches* `^manufacturer=.+` but only `.+` is replaced.

Lastly, the `.+` matches everything up to the end of the string or a trailing newline (`.` doesn't match newlines).

Answer (score 1):

You need to leverage the full power of regexes:

```
s/^manufacturer=\w+/manufacturer=XXX/ig
```

Comment: Thanks Aidan. Why have you got the '^' in front of manufacturer?

Comment: `^` is a zero-width assertion matching beginning of string.

Comment: Hehe I like *"leverage the full power of regexes"*